# Como lidar com usuário que rejeita edições corretas?

Tags: debate, perguntas, edições-sugeridas

Uma edição é sugerida numa resposta, a qual estava correta e foi **rejeitada**. Em seguida, o autor da resposta, o qual **rejeitou** a edição, a edita exatamente igual a que foi rejeitada pelo mesmo. Como proceder?

Comment: A propósito, me corrija se eu estiver errado quanto ao assunto que eu citei em minha resposta. Se eu estiver certo acho que você pode adicionar o link para a resposta em questão para dar o contexto correto à sua pergunta, pois do jeito que está está muito vago.

Comment: Qualquer problema fale com um moderador :)

Comment: Muito bom @utluiz :D

Comment: Tive um caso recente aqui mas preferi deixar quieto. É um membro com mais de 30 mil pontos. Ele removeu a minha edição, na qual eu corrigia alguns erros dele e ainda meio que fez um sarcasmo como se nada tivesse acontecido e como se não tivesse nada errado. Eu estava sem tempo para ficar de mimimi na internet e deixei pra lá. Nem vou postar aqui o link. O interessante é, ele fez uma afirmação errada na resposta, e eu poderia simplesmente dar um negativo. Mas, eu dei um positivo e corrigi o ponto falho de forma discreta. Ao invés de agradecer, ele reverteu o que fiz, mantendo o erro.

Comment: continuando.. só agora depois de 12 dias que eu fui dar uma olhada na fila de análise para ver quem editou.. Foi o prório autor da resposta que rejeitou a edição, obviamente porque ele deve ter mais privilégios de edição devido a alta pontuação. Isso é correto ? Isso não propicia um ambiente corrupto ? É como ter um concurso onde vc organiza e vc mesmo ganha .. rsrsrs que piada... é esse tipo de coisa que arranha a credibilidade do SO... Bom.. jogando a lama no vetilador para deixar claro rsrsrs: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27978

Comment: @DanielOmine passei por aqui e percebi que o teu comentário (e frustração) são por minha causa! Lamento ter causado isso. A minha intenção era somente usar HTML5/CSS3. Tu [argumentaste que o HTML4 e CSS2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57582/pegar-html-de-v%c3%a1rias-divs-com-o-mesmo-id/57599#comment118736_57599) ainda vão estar por aí algum tempo [e eu dei-te razão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57582/pegar-html-de-v%c3%a1rias-divs-com-o-mesmo-id/57599#comment118761_57599). Vou ser mais generoso na proxima vez, e, entretanto juntei um comentário na resposta.

Comment: tudo bem @Sergio , obrigado por responder e desculpe se houve alguma ofensa. Achei nobre de sua parte ao menos responder. Agora eu que fiquei com vergonha. Você parece usar português de Portugal, certo? Pode ser que eu tenha interepretado errado algum termo do seu idioma. Tem certos termos que parecem iguais ao do Brasil mas acabam tendo um sentido diferente. Exemplo, "Vou ser mais generoso na proxima". Eu sou brasileiro, e analisando o contexto e a forma como se expressa, parece que está debochando, entende?

Comment: @DanielOmine essa é um dos problemas do mundo _online_ :/ Citação: ["Além disso, na internet, as pessoas tendem a ser muito mais frias e desumanas do que na vida real."](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2347/3117). É difícil passar a tonalidade certa em uma mensagem escrita, as pessoas do outro lado podem entender de uma forma completamente diferente do que você quis dizer.

Comment: Além do mais, ok, obviamente que vi que vc concordou com o que comentei na resposta. O que eu fiquei surpreso é ao mesmo tempo que você concordou, você removeu a edição. Concordou mas não concordou? rsrs Decida-se. Exemplo, modifiquei "A solução" para "Uma solução". Fiz isso por mera questão gramatical. "A solução" aponta para um objeto definido, ou seja, como se fosse uma solução absoluta. Já o termo "Uma solução" aponta um objeto indefinido, representando que existe outras soluções e aquilo que apresentaste não é algo absoluto, entendeu?

Comment: E também adicionei as letras na nomenclatura dos IDs. Tudo bem discreto sem mudar nada no sentido da resposta original. Procurando ao máximo respeitar a resposta alheia.
Eu poderia ser hostil e passar por cima como a maioria faz. Dar um negativo e postar uma resposta própria para tentar ganhar votos. Mas eu acho isso muito mesquinho. Foi mais simples somente ajustar a resposta "perfeita" do outro colega e pronto. Estou aqui para aprender e para compartilhar e ser útil para o desenvolviumento coletivo, não para inflar o meu próprio ego com pontinhos e estrelinhas virtuais rsrsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine sim sou português, e curiosamente vivo na Suécia. O meu Português já não é o que era :) Já tem havido outros casos onde usei termos que em brasileiro significam outras coisas. Não é por mal, são versões da lingua mãe que partilhamos :)

Comment: Quando é assim @DanielOmine o melhor é falar com o próprio e esclarecer. Olhe aqui por exemplo nos comentários da resposta a esta pergunta.

Comment: @Sergio que eu tenha visto usas um ótimo português de Portugal. Alias tu e o Zuul são as pessoas que me mantiveram por aqui no meu inicio conturbado no SOpt. "Eles percebem-me" :P

Comment: Nunca me preocupei com essa questão de editar minha resposta, se alguém se deu ao trabalho de ler e fazer os ajustes necessários para que fique ainda mais interpretável eu até agradeço, só a questão mesmo de não mudar o sentido original

Comment: @JorgeB., entendo, mas achei melhor expor o caso com todos. Uma conversa particular não resolveria nada. Ele ficaria mantendo a pose e a razão dele. Aliás, continuou sem resolver nada. A resposta continua lá "errada". E sobre idioma, tem diferenças em pt e br, mas não ainda acho que ele esteja fazendo pouco caso disso. Do meu ponto de vista parece agir com cinismo. Não é possível que ninguem aqui não entenda de CSS para ver aquilo.. Como comentei, permitir esse tipo de ação é permitir um ambiente corrupto.

Comment: @DanielOmine depois de comentares, se o autor não mudar a resposta, podes sempre negativar para mostrar que achas que está errado. Mas o AR(Autor da Resposta) pode continuar a achar que está certa da forma dele.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade não foi o autor da resposta que rejeitou a edição, foram os usuários através da fila de análise, como você pode ver [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28277).

A sua sugestão de edição era na verdade uma tentativa de debater a resposta, enquanto na verdade as edições devem se limitar a consertar erros de digitação, formatação dentre outras coisas que **não alterem o sentido original da publicação**. (In)felizmente, você estava correta no fato de que existia um erro na resposta do autor, mas não era algo assim tão trivial que pudesse ser modificado sem o consentimento do mesmo. A ação mais apropriada nesse caso seria deixar um comentário ([que nem você fez em seguida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58403/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-postconstruct-e-o-construtor/58417#comment120573_58417)) para entrar em um acordo com o autor da resposta.

Assim como o renan, que disse nos comentários:

> apareceu pra mim aqui e acabei 'pulando' a análise justamente por não saber a diferença das anotações e o que isso iria influenciar no código.

eu também pulei essa análise na fila de edições. Mas nem todos os usuários da fila de análise pensam da mesma forma e nesse caso eu não os recrimino pois nem sempre o autor da publicação está presente para analisar a sugestão de edição ele mesmo, portanto, às vezes é melhor tomar uma ação do que deixar na fila de análises para sempre.

No seu caso, o autor da resposta em seguida concordou com você e fez a alteração que você havia sugerido desde o princípio, então eu daria esse problema como: **Resolvido** :)

Comment: **não alterem o sentido original do post**

Comment: @JorgeB. carma!!

Comment: Math, o @JorgeB. deve ter achado que você estava falando de "karma". Ele é português, provavelmente não conhece o sotaque do interior de São Paulo! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto eu entendi, aqui veem se muitas novelas brasileiras :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Sinto muito exportarmos isso para Portugal. Tinha tanta coisa melhor pra exportar!

Comment: Podia exportar as concorrentes do BBB :P